# Windows "disappeared" after Ubuntu istalled and system setup reset

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 but along Win 10 but my PC (Asus X55VD) kept to boot directly into Windows. I used boot-repair-disk, then I was able to select Ubuntu. But once I selected Windows Boot Manager to boot, the boot order changed back to the old state, booting Windows. I set the system setup to its default values, because changing boot order didn't help (the new boot order not saved for some reason).

After performed the reset, the windows boot options disappeared from the boot options, remained only Ubuntu.
Ubuntu works perfectly as far as I see.

I have an SSD as the main drive, with two partitions:

- `C:` for the OS (Windows)
- `E:` for all kinds of stuff (Windows)

And I have a HDD in the place of the optical drive for more space, with 2 partitions:

- One of them under Windows control
- I installed Ubuntu to the other.

From Ubuntu I can see Windows' files, system files and all stuff.
If it is possibly I would like to get back my Windows.

I have a `.txt` containing a report from boot-repair-disk.
However, I cannot understand it, hence I am not an expert unfortunately.

[image: Google drive link to bootinfo.txt]

I appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-n5KxE2YM1OqjlakM50-HF9mBMnYOZU4/view?usp=drivesdk   - - grub menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the BIOS is skipping the whole SSD while booting up, this is very common and it happened to me as well. You just have to go to the **BIOS** and **change** the boot hierarchy, put the **SSD before the HDD** and you should be good to go.

Anyway I'd recommend, based on my experience, using the grub boot manager. I could easily boot directly into Windows by putting the SSD right before the HDD, however is very easy for me booting from the HDD, because it will prompt me the grub menu, as it has detected another system, then select which one to use. By using two separate disks you don't have the risk of Windows messing the grub with its updates.

Comment: What do you mean by the "boot hierarchy"? Boot order or a completely different thing? Anyway, the BIOS don't even show the SSD as a bootable drive. I can only select the HDD in the options. However, when I start the system, it shows several options to boot into. I add an image, to show the grub menu. I don't understand a big part of it, and when I choose Windows Boot Manager(on \dev\sdb1) it enters an "prepare for automated repair" loop.

Comment: Now the problem is completely different, I checked your grub and those boot UEFI, EFI... shouldn't be there... I think that Windows has something messed up, as you should be able to boot from Windows choosing Windows Boot Manager. And the automated repair loop makes me think that the installation of Windows might be missing some files. My recommendation is backing up your Windows personal files from Ubuntu, as you can access them from the file manager, and then reinstall Windows, you will use the Windows boot manager to choose the OS you are using.

Comment: Yes, I had the suspicion that I might very well need to reinstall windows. When I reinstall windows to the SSD, it won't mess up the HDD right? And what about the partition the SSD has already? Will a reinstall format the drive and clear everything? It's a long time since I last installed windows.

Comment: When you reinstall Windows you will have to format yor SSD, therefore I recommend you to back up your personal files using Ubuntu, once you got them, reinstall Windows. It won't mess up the HDD because it's just a clean install on a separate disk. Also, Windows can't read your Ubuntu partition because its file system is uncompatible, so no risks for your Ubuntu installation as well.

Comment: Don't you know, how can I retrieve my Windows's license? Because the "reset this PC" option doesn't work. Windows 8 came with my laptop, 6 years ago. Is there any way to find that key, or I have to buy it again?

Comment: If the license came with your laptop it may be a OEM key, so you can reactivate it once you reinstall Windows.